# Using variable in sed as an output of previous command

Tags: awk, sed, grep

Below is the output of my 'COMMAND' command .The output format is FILE:LINENO:PATTERN. I want to 
take the below command output values in diff variables and use them in 'sed' command mentioned at the bottom.

```
<COMMAND> 
./core.pkglist:16:package linux-release     6Server     9.0.3
./core.pkglist:18:package release-server   6Server     6.9.0.4.0.1.el6
./core.pkglist:32:package upstart                 0.6.5       16.el6
./core.pkglist:33:package libnih                  1.0.1       7.el6
```

I want to replace it with the command sed with inputs from the output of above command like:

```
sed "$var1 s/$var2/$c' $var3
```

that helps me run virtually the below command:

```
sed '16s/9.0.3/$c/' core.pkglist
```

1)The value 16 above should come from a variable like:

```
var1=$(COMMAND |awk -F':' '{print $2}')
```

2)9.0.3 should come from a variable.

```
var2=$(COMMAND |awk -F '{print $4}')
```

3)core.pkglist should come from a variable.

```
var3=$(COMMAND |awk -F '{print $1}')
```

4) $c is another command output

Comment: Sorry it is not clear, could you please post simple sample input and expected sample output and let us know then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
v3=$(echo Hello world); # Stupid examples of variables set from output commands
v1=$(wc -l <<< $v3);
v2=$(awk '{print $1}' <<< $v3);
c=$(echo Good morning); 
sed "${v1}s/$v2/$c/" <<< $v3 # Use double quotes instead of singles
# echo $v3 |  sed "${v1}s/$v2/$c/" works as well
```

Returns :

```
Good morning world
```